# conversion of Julian date to standard format

Tags: r, date

I am a new chap who is just getting hang of R, so like to seek your help. My current date format shows 0 and 19243. I am not able to convert it to standard format while keeping the zero as it is. So your simple and straight forward solution would be be highly appreciated.

Good da

Current date format:

[image: Screen short of current date format]

I tried with various function such as.Date, julian2date, and julian function...didn't work out in my favour.

Comment: See the linked post, check if it works in your case. If it doesn't, provide example data input and the codes you have tried.